# CrudRepository explanation needed

Tags: java, spring, persistence, crud

While learning spring I found out **Crud Repository** and **find by** which i didn't understood, Can any one please tell me what is CRUD and how to use them its syntax and all.
I know CRUD stands for Create,Read,Update,Delete. but don't know how to use it and what is find by?

Comment: Assuming you're talknig about spring-data-jpa, you should read the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Answer (score 1):

CRUD stands for **Create, Read, Update** and **Delete**. These are the normal functions used in any kind of **Data Access Layer**. [Repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is the design pattern used to implement the CRUD functionality of the application. Regarding the Spring CRUD reporitories in particular, you could check [this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html).

While the repository is a very famous pattern, very commonly used, I would suggest keeping the [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) risks.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I ll go through that tuotorial